# Should I use Session State or Viewstate to store and save information in asp?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, session-state

Viewstate or sessionstate? This is to save the variables to a specific user then display them on the output page. Btw, these variables will be saved on atleast 5 different pages before it's outputted, so I want to be able to store them. Thanks!

Comment: Please enter this in Google search box - **[site:stackoverflow.com SessionState or Viewstate](https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+SessionState+or+Viewstate)**

Comment: @Win the problem is that google doesn't help me, this site is way better and more helpful

Comment: **[site:stackoverflow.com SessionState or Viewstate](https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+SessionState+or+Viewstate)** will give you all previous answers in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewstate typically stores data for a single page. Session state stores data for a session. If you are planning (as you have said) on persisting values over a several pages I would go with session state.